# Finding Basic Limits

Tags: limits

> For the function given by $f(x) = |x − 2| + 42$ and $x → 2$, make a guess of the limit, and then prove your
>   assertion using the formal definition of a limit.

This was confusing; please help.

My guess is $f(x) = 42$ as $x$ approaches $2$.

Comment: Do you have a guess for the limit?

Comment: Wouldn't the limit of f(x) as x tends to 2 be equal to 42?

Comment: I would guess that the limit is $42$, and then prove it according to what was taught during the last class.

Comment: Good guess! Now prove it!

Comment: My guess is f(x) = 42 as x approaches 2 right?

Comment: Well, you will be sure once you have proved it. That is why we prove things!

Comment: I was more concerned witht he latter haha "formal definition of a limit"

Comment: A shoot do we just have to f(x+h) as x approaches 2?

Answer (score 1):

Claim: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 42$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, choose $\delta = \epsilon$. If $0 < |x-2| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-42| = ||x-2|+42-42| = |x-2| < \delta = \epsilon$, hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value in this function compels us to split the domain. The plot makes this clear:

[image: The continuous function with a discontinuous first derivative.]

The function can be written as
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}  x + 40,  & \text{x > 2} \\
-x + 44, & \text{x < 2}
\end{cases}
$$

The limit $\lim f(x)$ exists when the limit from the right matches the limit from the left:
$$
\lim_{x\to2^{-}}f(x) = \lim_{x\to2^{+}} f(x)
$$

Consider the limit from the right $(x > 2)$: the claim is that as $x\to c=2$, $f(x)\to L = 42$,

Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every expression $0<|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ where the $L$ is the limit.
$$
|f(x)-L| = |x + 40 - 42| = |x - 2| < \epsilon
$$
This condition is satisfied whenever $0 < |x - 2| < \delta$ which implies $\delta = \epsilon$. Because $\epsilon >0$, $\delta > 0$.
The left handed limit is a simple extension.

For familiarization, construct sequences $x_n = 2 \pm 10^{-n}$. Certainly $\epsilon = \delta$.

From the left we have

\begin{array}{ll}
 n & x_n & f(x_n) \\\hline
 1 & 1.9 & 42.1 \\
 2 & 1.99 & 42.01 \\
 3 & 1.999 & 42.001 \\
 4 & 1.9999 & 42.0001 \\
\end{array}

and from the right we see

\begin{array}{lll}
 n & x_n & f(x_n) \\\hline
 1 & 2.1 & 42.1 \\
 2 & 2.01 & 42.01 \\
 3 & 2.001 & 42.001 \\
 4 & 2.0001 & 42.0001 \\
\end{array}

Answer (score -1):

A function can have a limit so long as for $f(x)=L$ such that there is a distance $\delta$ to the left and right of $a$ such that there correspond to $x$ values that produce $y$ outputs that are $\epsilon$ values on the top and bottom of the limit.

$|x-a|>\delta$ such that $|f(x)-L| > \epsilon$

$f(2)=42$ as $x$ approaches 
So....
$|x-2|>\delta$
say $\epsilon=0.01$, and we have values $y=42.01$ and $y=41.99$ casing $42$.

If $42.01=|x-2|+42$, then $2.01=x$.

If $41.99=|x-2|+42$, then $-0.99+2=1.99$.

If $2+\delta=2.01$, $2-\delta=1.99$, then $\delta=0.01$.

Hence there exists these two $\delta$ values such that there is also an $\epsilon$ distance between $42$.

Comment: You got the inequalities backwards :S